# Angular 2 Routing without hashtag in IE

Tags: angular2-routing

I'm building angular 2 app and hitting to problem of making ng2 routing with pathMatch:full working in IE. For example: this link: https://angularspree.firebaseapp.com/auth/login. If I start from https://angularspree.firebaseapp.com and go to login, it works. If I refresh the page, it shows Page Not Found error. Does anyone know how to fix it in IE browser ?

Comment: facing similar issue,how did you solve  this issue?thanks